# Reading a binary file in read mode Python 3 - passes on Windows, fails on Linux

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file, binary

I am executing this piece of code against

Python on Windows

`'3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'`

and

Python on Linux

`'3.6.6 (default, Mar 29 2019, 00:03:27) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]'`

The code writes some bytes into a file using `wb` mode and then reads it as `r` plain text. I understand that I should be reading as bytes (`rb`), but I am curious why does it break on Linux while passing on Windows?

```py
import os
import tempfile
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
temp_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'write_file')

expected_bytes = bytearray([123, 3, 255, 0, 100])
with open(temp_file, 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(expected_bytes)

with open(temp_file, 'r', newline='') as fh:
    actual = fh.read()
```

Exception raised on Linux:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/home/.../lib64/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Getting default system encoding (with `sys.getdefaultencoding()`) shows
`'utf-8'` on both machines.

Comment: Probably because the default encoding used when reading on your Windows system is not utf-8, but some encoding like latin-1 in which all bytes correspond to a valid character.

Comment: Hm, I just checked with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and it is utf-8 on both machines...

Comment: From the doc for `open`: 'The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding() returns) ' - what does this one return?

Comment: Try `locale.getpreferredencoding()`

Comment: Also: sys.getdefaultencoding() : Return the name of the current default string encoding used by the Unicode implementation.

Comment: Aha! `locale.getpreferredencoding()` gives `'cp1252'` on Windows and `'UTF-8'` on Linux. This is it then? @ThierryLathuille, feel free to post an answer elaborating a bit on the cause - I'd be happy to accept!

Comment: This must be it! I added an answer, hope it answers all your questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a file in text mode, so with `'rt'` (where both 'r' and 't' are the default), everything you read from the file gets transparently decoded on the fly and returned as `str` objects, as explained in [Text I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o).

You can force the encoding to use when opening the file, like:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

As explained in the documenation for [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever
>   locale.getpreferredencoding() returns), but any text encoding
>   supported by Python can be used. See the codecs module for the list of
>   supported encodings.

(Note that `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is something unrelated: it returns the name of the current default string encoding used by the Unicode implementation)

As you stated in the comments, on your system, `locale.getpreferredencoding()` gives 'cp1252' on Windows and 'UTF-8' on Linux.

[CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is a single byte encoding in which each byte corresponds to a character. So, whatever file you read, the data it contains can be turned into a string.

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), though, uses a variable width encoding in which not all sequences of bytes are valid and represent a character. That's why trying to read your file on your Linux system failed when some byte couldn't be decoded.

Answer (score 2):

If you have written the file out as bytes, you should read it in as bytes.

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "rb")
```

If you read it in as text (using `"r"` or `"rt"`) then an attempt will be made to decode it into Unicode. What encoding is used by default is platform-dependent. But you clearly don't want it decoded at all.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I do understand that reading binary as plain text is meaningless, I was just curious what was the difference between environments that showed different behaviour

Comment: Well, there you have it. When reading a textfile, be explicit about the encoding that you expect your file to be in.